# JQuery DataTables sorting - putting zero last

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I am currently using JQuery's datatables on my bootstrap table.
Currently, sorting puts zeroes first and then the rest of the numbers, like so->
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
I want the zeroes to be last, like so -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0

I haven't found any possible solutions yet.
I'm currently not posting any code because I think it's irrelevant. If anybody wishes to see it, please say so.
Regards and thanks in advance.

```
$('#clubLeague-results').DataTable({

    "order": [[2, 'asc']],
    "bFilter": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bDeferRender": true,
    columnDefs: [

        { orderable: false, targets: 0 },
        { orderable: false, targets: 1 },
        { orderable: false, targets: 3 },
        { orderable: false, targets: 5 },
        { orderable: false, targets: 6 },
        { type: 'natural', targets: 2 },
        { type: 'natural', targets: 3 }

    ],

});
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/4nd3j80L/)

Comment: can you send the code, even if it is useless

Comment: Hello! Sure! Here it is:

https://jsfiddle.net/4nd3j80L/

I hope it doesn't look very harsh, because I'm using razor view.

Comment: can you add in the code ! for everyone

Comment: try to make 0 equal to a bigger number

Comment: What do you mean ? How can I make 0 have a bigger value without changing it's value ?

Comment: You could add a second (hidden) column, which contains 1 where your column is 0 and 0 otherwise, then use multi-column sorting, as per https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderData

Comment: This seems like a really good idea, although I have absolutely no idea how to implement it. Took me about 3 hours to set up this tiny JS. Are there any other ways to do it or should I start trying ?

Comment: Show me the resulting html (not the templating code with @ symbols) in the fiddle, and I might be able to adapt it for you

Comment: Or someone might

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a hidden `span` in the columns where value is 0 that has a higher value than the highest possible number. Say the column where the 0..9 numbers are is `target: 2`

```
columnDefs: [
  { "targets": [2], "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
    if (data === 0 || data === "0") {
      return '<span style="display:none">999</span>' + data;
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  }
]
```

Might not be too elegant, but it's the easiest way to accomplish this.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't work, not sure why. I modified the target to 3 as it should be, but the 0s are still at the top.

Comment: Does the column have something else than 0, i.e. does `if (data === 0 || data === "0")` ever return `true`? Debug it with `console.log`. You probably also need to have just one `targets: 3` line in `columnDefs`

Comment: I am sorry, it was my mistake. I had added a hidden TD previously so I had to move my index ++. Great solution and thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to change the value used for sorting using what Datatables refers to as [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data).  Seems the best bet is to set the value to [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).  Here is example code:

```
columnDefs: [
  {targets: 1,
   render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
     if (type === 'sort') {
       return data === 0 ? Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER : data;
     }
     return data;
   }}
]
```

You can see it in action here:
http://live.datatables.net/rogufeku/1/edit